# Computing singular homology of a chain complex.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have the following chain complex $A:  0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{0}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0$. When I try to compute the homology, I use the definition $H_n(X) = \ker \partial_n / \operatorname{Im} \partial_{n+1}$. I was wondering if anyone could tell me if the following is the right homology for this chain complex: $H(A): 0 \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 0$. If this is not right, could anyone tell me why it is not right and how I could fix it? Thanks!

EDIT: Sorry, I realized I forgot the in the chain complex $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to know the non-trivial map $f \colon \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ to know what is the precise homology. I'll assume your complex starts at $n = 0$. Just by using the definition, you get

$$ H_0(A) = 0, \\
H_1(A) = \ker(f) / \operatorname{Im}(0) \cong \ker(f), \\
H_2(A) = \mathbb{Z} / \operatorname{Im}(f) = \operatorname{coker}(f), \\
H_3(A) = 0.
$$

After the edit, we see that $H_1(A) \cong H_2(A) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ while all other homology groups are zero.

Comment: Thanks @levap. I edited the question, so hopefully now the question is more clear.

Comment: @user284639: I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Chain homology doesn't really have arrows between the terms.

Let's write your complex as $(C_n)$ with $C_0=C_1=\Bbb Z$ and all other
$C_n=\{0\}$. I presume the differential $d:C_1\to C_0$ is the identity on $\Bbb Z$. At $C_1$ the image of $C_2\to C_1$ is zero, and the kernel of $C_1\to C_0$ is zero; so $H_1(C_*)=0$. At $C_0$ the image of $C_1\to C_0$
is $\Bbb Z$ and the kernel of $C_0\to C_{-1}$ is also $\Bbb Z$. So $H_0(C_*)$ is $\Bbb Z/\Bbb Z$, also the zero group.

You've edited the question to make the only map zero. A chain complex $C_*$
with all differentials zero has $H_n(C_*)=C_*$. That is because at $C_n$ the kernel is $C_n$ but the image is $0$.

Comment: Thanks @Lord Shark the Unknown. I've edited my question to be more clear when specifying the map.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!